# can't add a collection in firebase fireStore

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying  to add  a collection in fireBase  fireStore  so i  used  this function  .collection.(doc).set  ; the collection was  not  created and the console  show  error register , and despite  that i find  the new  user in authentification in firebase , i hope that  i find the good  solution . i'm getting crazy

```
  <div class="uk-position-small uk-position-center uk-overlay uk-overlay-default">
      <form #f="ngForm"  (ngSubmit)="register(f)">
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-inline">
              <span class="uk-form-icon" uk-icon="icon: happy"></span>
              <input class="uk-input" type="text" name="firstName" #firstName="ngModel" ngModel required>
              <p class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="firstName.errors?.required && firstName.touched">this input firstName and lastName are required</p>

          </div>
      </div>


      <div class="uk-margin">
        <div class="uk-inline">
<textarea class="uk-input"   cols="28" rows="10" placeholder="bio" name="bio" #bio="ngModel" ngModel bio required></textarea>
<p class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="bio.errors?.required && bio.touched">this bio isrequired</p>

</div>
    </div>
      <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-inline">
              <span class="uk-form-icon" uk-icon="mail"></span>
              <input class="uk-input" type="text" name="email" #email="ngModel" ngModel email required>
              <p class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="email.errors?.required && email.touched">this input email is required</p>

          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-inline">
              <span class="uk-form-icon uk-form-icon-flip" uk-icon="icon: lock"></span>
              <input class="uk-input" type="password" name="password" #password="ngModel" ngModel password required minlength="8">
              <p class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="password.errors?.required && password.touched">this input password is required</p>
              <p class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="password.errors?.minlength && password.touched">this input password should +8 caratere</p>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-margin">
        <div class="uk-inline">
            <span class="uk-form-icon uk-form-icon-flip" uk-icon="icon: lock"></span>
            <input class="uk-input" type="password" name="confirmPassword" #confirmPassword="ngModel" ngModel required minlength="8">
            <p class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="confirmPassword.errors?.required && password.errors?.minlength && confirmPassword.touched">this input confirmpassword is required</p>
            <p class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="password.value!==confirmPassword.value && password.touched">not equal</p>
        </div>
    </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>

    </form>
    </div>
```

```
        export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

          constructor(private as:AuthService , private fs:AngularFirestore , private route:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  register(f){
   // console.log(f.value)

   let data=f.value
    this.as.signUp(data.email,data.password ).then((user)=>{

    this.fs.collection("users").doc(user.user.uid).set({
  firstName:data.firstName,
  email:data.email,
  bio:data.bio,
  uid:data.user.user.uid
})
.then(()=>{
 console.log('done')
 // this.route.navigateByUrl('/home')
})
})
.catch(()=>{
console.log('error register')
    })
  }

}
```

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private fa:AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user=this.fa.user
   }
  signUp(email,password){
 return this.fa.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
  }
  signIn(email,password){
    return this.fa.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
  }

}
```

Comment: Try to log the error and post the error here.

Comment: error register  ,  just  the error  of  the  console ,  but  the  strange  thing that  i find  the new  user in authentification , is there something wrong in my function ?

Comment: maybe  should  i change  something in security rules in  firestore ??

Comment: That's not the error I mean. Change the catch to `catch(e => console.log(e))` so you can see the error detail.

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')
    at register.component.ts:28
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:28680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:371)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134)
    at zone.js:1276
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28667)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178)

Comment: I think the error is when you call `user.user.id`. The user object is `undefined`.

Comment: i called him  from  here ,  authservice                                                                                                export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private fa:AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user=this.fa.user
   }
  signUp(email,password){
 return this.fa.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
  }
  signIn(email,password){
    return this.fa.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
  }

}

Comment: Try to log `user` and `data.user` and see which one is `undefined`

Comment: sorry  but how  can i do  thata ??  which code should  i  write ??

Comment: console.log('User', user)
console.log('Data user', data.user)

Put it before `collection.doc.set`.

Comment: i did it and   the  console  show me that                                                                                               User {user: Dm, credential: null, additionalUserInfo: sg, operationType: 'signIn'}
register.component.ts:23 Data user undefined
register.component.ts:36 error register
register.component.ts:37 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')

Comment: So your `data.user` is `undefined` and `data` is from `f.value`. There is some value missing from `f`. Please recheck it. You can also post how you call register(f).

Comment: i editet  the  post  bro  and  i put the  html file  too  , i'm checking it i dont  know  exactly   bro  what's wrong

Comment: I think what you want to write is not `data.user.user.uid` but `user.user.uid`

Comment: hey  bernhard  i deleted  uid:user.user.uid  from set {} and  it's worked  the collection was created  and i found the  user 
 so what's the problem exactly ?

Comment: The problem is on that line `uid: data.user.user.uid`. You are trying to access user object from `data`, but as you can see from your HTML `form`, there is only `firstName`, `bio`, and `email` field, thus you can access it by `data.firstName`, `data.bio`, and `data.email`.

Comment: any way   it worked now  , hope that's dont  do  errors for me later   and  thank you so much for  your time and ur   help <3

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning promises in your chain so your code is blowing right by them. If this doesn't solve your issue, then the problem is in your `signUp` code and you'd have to post that for more help.

```js
register(f){
  let data=f.value
  this.as.signUp(data.email, data.password).then((user) => {
    // You need to return this promise. Right now, your code
    // is blowing right by it and immediately calling the next `then`
    return this.fs.collection("users").doc(user.user.uid).set({
      firstName: data.firstName,
      email: data.email,
      bio: data.bio,
      uid: data.user.user.uid
    })
  }).then(() => {
    // This code block has now waited for the doc to be set
    console.log('done')
    // this.route.navigateByUrl('/home')
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('error register')
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `register(f)`? Your signup looks fine but I still believe you're missing a promise chain somewhere which is why the signUp code works but creating the collection doesn't.